# Global model in spine.js application

Tags: html, model, coffeescript, spine.js

I have web application written with `Spine.js`. It has 2 language translations. I want to store current application's translation in Spine Model.

My model:

```
class Translation extends Spine.Model

    @configure "Translation", "lang"

    @getLang: ->
        Translation.all()

module.exports = Translation
```

I have function which changes translation in application and i save new translation to the model in this function:

```
  changeLang: (locale) ->
    lang = Translation.create({lang: locale})
    lang.save()
```

But when i try to fetch data from `Translation` model from another controller i get empty result:

```
Translation = require("models/translation")
...
alert(Translation.getLang())
```

I got empty alert. How can i make it correctly?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The `Translation.all()` [returns copies](http://spinejs.com/api/models) of all instances of `Translation` class. It seems, from snippets you provided, that when you call `Translation.getLang()` there are no such instances. You should make sure that `changeLang` has been called (I suppose that it is the only place where new instances of `Translation` are created) before calling `alert(Translation.getLang())`.